# why does this script not execute in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-detection

I'm trying to run a very simple browser detect script and it executes just fine in Safari and Chrome (running on a Mac) but doesn't execute at all in Firefox. I can boil it down to the simplest possible form, and it still doesn't execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/^.*Chrome.*$/)) {break;}
else {
location="howdy.html"
}
</script>
```

This has been perplexing me for hours now. Anyone have an idea? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all, in any browser. `break` is for loops and switches, not `if` statements (what are you trying to do there anyway?). https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Loop_Statements/Break_Statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `location="howdy.html"` to `location.href="howdy.html"`

And also, stop doing browser-sniffing. Do feature detection in your JavaScript to make a more robust application in the long-term.

Comment: CMS: *please* stop using is.gd for urls. It's a sore on my status bar ;)

Comment: this worked like a charm. thank you so much. And duly noted about Browser-sniffing.

Comment: @Dan Sinker: really? *This* was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/break) statement in a wrong place, I'm sure you are getting a syntax error, since it's illegal to use `break` outside a loop or a switch.

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) Spec. Reference:

**12.8 The `break` Statement**

**Syntax**

`BreakStatement` :

`break` *[no `LineTerminator` here]* `Identifieropt` ;

**Semantics**

A program is considered **syntactically incorrect** if either of the following is true:

- The program contains a `break` statement without the optional `Identifier`, which is not nested, directly or indirectly (but not crossing function boundaries), within an `IterationStatement` or a `SwitchStatement`.
- The program contains a `break` statement with the optional `Identifier`, where `Identifier` does not appear in the label set of an enclosing (but not crossing function boundaries) `Statement`.

Comment: Apparently that wasn't it. WTF? Is there a case you know of where the OPs code is *not* a syntax error?

Comment: Nope, I don't know any case... `break` **must** be inside a loop or a labeled statement...

Comment: JFTR, added ES reference... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a side issue, but it's too big for a comment.

Looking at your regex, I have to think there's something wrong there.  `.*` matches *everything*, and since regular expressions are greedy by default the first `.*` would match on the entire rest of the string, leaving no chance to match the `Chrome` part and forcing a failure.  Some engines might be smart enough understand what you mean, but I would still simplify that to just `/Chrome/`.

Comment: That is wrong. Any regular expression engine that is really a regular expression language (and not just doing some sort of lame globbing) will match that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If me, I will do like this

```
if(!/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
   location.href="howdy.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to tag errors logged when I'm testing code on multiple browsers.

It gets the browser name and version right for the browsers I test on-IE, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Chrome. But I call it navigator.sayswho because that's all it is- who the navigator says it is.

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
 var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
 var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
 if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
 M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
 return M;
})();
```